# How to solve problem with saving data from consumed api

Tags: spring-boot, rest

I run into the problem where I can't save data to database because of next exception

```
Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [class com.project.beerapp.domain.Beer] and content type [application/json;charset=utf-8]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `com.project.beerapp.domain.Beer` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `com.project.beerapp.domain.Beer` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)
at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
```

This is my Entity class:

```
public class Beer implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;
private String name;
private String description;
```

}

In my main class I have this logic for saving data:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(BeerAppApplication.class, args);

    ResponseEntity<Beer> response = restTemplate.getForEntity("https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers", Beer.class);

    Beer entity = response.getBody();

    beerRepository.saveAndFlush(entity);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as you can see if you open https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers on your browser, that is an ARRAY of OBJECTS, not just one object, therefore instead of

```
ResponseEntity<Beer> response = restTemplate.getForEntity("https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers", Beer.class);
```

you should do:

```
ResponseEntity<Beer[]> response = restTemplate.getForEntity("https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers", Beer[].class);
//                 ^^                                                                               ^^
Beer[] entities = response.getBody();
```

Comment: Oh yeah! What should I parse then to repository #save method ?

Comment: @markz you can use the `saveAll` or just loop over the array and save individually if you need sone logic